# Custom background for the homepage only, WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to work with theme options in WordPress. I made dynamic background image using

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', array(
                'wp-head-callback' => 'custom_background_cb',
                // Background color default
                'default-color' => 'fff',
                // Background image default
                'default-image' => trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'images/bg.jpg',


            ) );
```

This work for me, but I want image only on homepage background, and on other pages only color. I tried something with

```
if ( is_front_page() )
    {
        custom_background_cb();
    }
```

but it doesn't work. I need some other suggestions or solutions. Please help!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is solution:

```
function wpse_67480_background_frontend()
{
    if ( is_front_page() )
    {
       _custom_background_cb();
    }
}
```

Only change array member to this 'wp-head-callback' => 'wpse_67480_background_frontend'